# Edit a find -exec echo command to include a grep for a string

Tags: bash, grep, find, exec

So I have the following command which looks for a series of files and appends three lines to the end of everything found.  Works as expected.

```
find /directory/ -name "file.php" -type f -exec sh -c "echo -e 'string1\string2\nstring3\n' >> {}" \;
```

What I need to do is also look for any instance of string1, string2, or string3 in the find ouput of file.php *prior* to echoing/appending the lines so I don't append a file unnecessarily.  (This is being run in a crontab)

Using `| grep -v "string"` after the `find` breaks the `-exec` command.

How would I go about accomplishing my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably do it in a few steps: find your files, use grep -v to exclude the oens with your string, then pass the filenames to xargs or something to do the actual appending.

Comment: Do you need to add the lines only if none of them exist or add them all if any of them don't exist or add only the missing ones?

Comment: Are you trying to look for string1, string2 or string3 in file.php?  If that is the case grep has an option in which it reads the list of patterns (which are specified in a file) to be found in file/s.

Comment: Should any instance of those three strings exist, I have no need to append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `-exec` command isn't safe for strings with spaces.

You want something like this instead (assuming finding any of the strings is reason not to add any of the strings).

```
find /directory/ -name "file.php" -type f -exec sh -c "grep -q 'string1|string2|string3' \"\$1\" || echo -e 'string1\nstring2\nstring3\n' >> \"\$1\"" - {} \;
```

To explain the safety issue.

`find` places `{}` in the command it runs as a single argument but when you splat that into a double-quoted string you lose that benefit.

So instead of doing that you pass the file as an argument to the shell and then use the positional arguments in the shell command with quotes.

The command above simply chains the `echo` to a failure from `grep` to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Etan,

This command seems to hang indefinitely.  No errors or output of any kind.

Comment: @subt3xt Oops, missed the argument to grep. Fixing.

Comment: Etan,

I'm not met with the following output.

'grep: : No such file or directory
-: : No such file or directory'

Comment: @subt3xt Needed to escape the `$` too. Try that. I usually use `'` on the outer command to avoid this.

Comment: After escaping it, the command works beautifully.  Thanks for the help and education.  I really appreciate it!